# User Interaction Improvements to Flyspell Correct Word

Tags: user-interface, emacs, spell-checking, flyspell

I think the behavior of `flyspell-correct-word` should be extended to a command that corrects all occurrences of the misspelled word of interest. This of course is not relevant for syntactic errors in the underlying spelling correction. I don't know if aspell/ispell supports such kinds of corrections. It would also like to combine the two into a command that queries the user whether he wants to correct *next* occurrence in a `query-replace` manner (y,n,q,Y,N,!). Has anybody implemented any of these ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following code to your .emacs, this seems to do what you're requesting (though it does not prompt you for replacements (that seemed a bit cumbersome)):

```
(setq flyspell-insert-function 'flyspell-insert-and-replace-all)
(defvar flyspell-last-replacements nil)
(defun flyspell-insert-and-replace-all (word)
  (unless (eq flyspell-auto-correct-pos pos) ; same check as done in flyspell-auto-correct-word
    (setq flyspell-last-replacements nil))
  (save-excursion
    (dolist (word-markers flyspell-last-replacements)
      (delete-region (car word-markers) (cdr word-markers))
      (goto-char (car word-markers))
      (insert word)))
  (insert word)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((do-replacement (not flyspell-last-replacements)))
      (while (re-search-forward (concat "\\<" flyspell-auto-correct-word "\\>") nil t)
        (replace-match word)
        ;; and, when doing first search/replace, record all the positions
        (when do-replacement
          (let ((end-marker (point-marker))
                (begin-marker (make-marker)))
            (set-marker begin-marker (- (point) (length word)))
            (set-marker-insertion-type end-marker t)
            (set-marker-insertion-type begin-marker nil)
            (add-to-list 'flyspell-last-replacements (cons begin-marker end-marker))))))))
```